# Does screen protector really protect anti-relfective coating in Macboon pro Retina display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mac-pro

I have a MAC Book pro 15" built in end of 2014. It has a known issue of [anti-reflective coating](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/11/17/apple-extends-free-staingate-repairs/). I got Apple to replace them twice and I am not sure if they change it again as I entering 5 years soon).

Since I got new display recently, I am thinking of protecting my display so it does not happen again.

Now, my question is:

Is anti-reflective coating of the display better protected under display protection or it fades faster since the screen protector is in direct contact with the coating?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the problem with the anti-reflective coating is that it slowly delaminates. I.e. the coating simply comes off the screen. The cause of it does not seem to be heat, but rather pressure from outside sources or just time passing.

In that light, I don't think a screen protector will protect you against this delamination. Any pressure exerted on the screen protector will also affect the coating. Instead I'm worried that the screen protector will actually make it worse as it will put a (small) weight on the coating at all times.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same fear as well. But at the same time not sure what go do differently. I am expecting this delamination happens in 3-6 month

Comment: I don’t think you can do anything to stop it I’m afraid :-(